# Hard to pray and keep wudu

Tags: wudu

As-salāmu ʿalaykum,

I have flatulence issue, I find it very hard to keep wudu. I have read that you have to do one wudu before the prayer time starts and my wudu will last until the next prayer time. I am manzoor because of my issue and I need to redo a new wudu for each prayer. What is the ruling if I find it hard to even do wudu because of this issue and in Ramadan I find it extremely hard and I have to repeat wudu a few times?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam.. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. What do you mean by "manzoor"? Secondly why wudu' is hard for you? You have to perform wudu' five times a day and find it hard? To even try answering your question you should share all necessary information with us. But you must be aware that this is not a fatwa site.

Answer (score -2):

Salaam. 
If you find it difficult and your conscience is truthful regarding the fact that there is no way you can do wudhu, then do tiyamam. 
Allah knows what is in your heart.

Comment: Tayamum is only an option if either water is absent, or water would cause you harm (kill you for instance).

Comment: Do not be so extreme. Islam is made to be easy for us, not difficult. So if the person is saying they find doing Wudhu very difficult, and they are being honest about it i.e. that there is no way they can use water, then tayamum is an option.

Comment: do you have any evidence to support your claims?

Comment: The religion is easy, beautiful and simply perfect. Why make things hard? The Qur’an reads: “Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship.” (Qur’an, 2:185)

Comment: @DaudAhmad Bruv, the Tayammum can only be justified if he is sick. Flatulence is just an annoyance, and is just as big a problem with Tayammum as it is with Wudu. If doing Wudu too often is hard, then that is not a reason to do Tayammum.

Comment: @Medi1Saif You're right dude. The OP isn't sick, he/she is just finding it hard to do Wudu, which doesn't justify Tayammum.

Comment: @DaudAhmad this is using an evidence out of context, why didn't you post the full verse? It describes the release for those who can't or are allowed not to fast due to illness and travel. Each release or exemption is related to specific conditions. Tayyamum is not a replacement for wudu' unless water is inaccessible, or would cause harm. This kind of smattering and generalization plus giving a fatwa without wisdom is dangerous: Allah says: "And do not pursue that of which you have no knowledge. Indeed, the hearing, the sight and the heart - about all those [one] will be questioned." (17:36).

Comment: It is neither in your nor my hand or knowledge to speak out a fatwa. Even a scholar wouldn't do so unless he knows each fact and here the matter doesn't sound like hardship (as defined by scholars), but as inconvenience which certainly is not a reason for a release and if so this release certainly not be Tayyamum. Allah also says: "And do not say about what your tongues assert of untruth, "This is lawful and this is unlawful," to invent falsehood about Allah . Indeed, those who invent falsehood about Allah will not succeed." (16:116).